# creating a random function that only gives integers in Processing

Tags: random, processing

I'm trying to use the random() function in Processing in terms of an array, so random index #s are selected each time. I need all my random numbers to be integers for the array to work, is there any way I can specify the random function so it only returns whole numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Just cast the returned value into an int:

```
int index = (int) random(maxValue);
```

This will **truncate** the number so that it no longer contains a decimal part.

Comment: And if you want wrap that in a function like `int intRand(maxValue){return (int) random(maxValue); }`